# How can we store textfield values in pdf in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, export

I want to store textfield values in pdf file i.e I need to export form values to pdf file just for back up purpose as I cant completely rely on app database so how can I achieve this. Can somebody help me pls. Or can we export data in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

> `I cant completely rely on app database`

Millions of apps rely on Databases! what about XML storage?

XML will be easy to store, easy to retrieve values.

---

I believe you're looking for **[xlslib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/index.php)**
Good Luck.

Comment: Then to i want my data to stored in pdf or Xls file

Comment: i am able to open pdf but unable to write in it.
check this link http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/08/creating-a-multi-page-pdf-document-on-iphoneipod-touchipad-with-encryption/